# Animate Arrow button while swiping bottomSheet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, bottom-sheet

I got a bottomsheet upon which, while swiping i need to animate arrow button indicating weather user swiping up or down?[image]

Here is my Sample Test one, while swiping the bottom sheet as you can see in the image, the arrow button at the bottom should rotate downward while swiping up, and on swiping down button should rotate upwards.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it is achievable using `BottomSheetCallback`. You just need to rotate the view by offset provided by the callback. For Example :-

```
// set callback for changes
bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        yourView.setRotation(slideOffset * 180);
    }
});
```

Comment: 360 will completely rotate the view. we need to rotate the view by half of that, hence 180 degrees, simple math. Just for a demo, change the 180 to 360. You'll come to know, :-). Happy to help

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sachin's answer is great.

Here's another solution, by maintaining the previous state of the bottomsheet.

```
  int  previousBottomSheetState = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED

  bottom_sheet.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                //to prevent rotation of the arrow if the users swipes down or up again, even when its already collapsed or expanded.
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED && newState != previousBottomSheetState) {
                    //update my bottomsheet state.
                    previousBottomSheetState = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED;
                    (yourView).animate().rotationXBy(180).start();
                } else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED && newState != previousBottomSheetState) {
                    previousBottomSheetState = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED;
                    (yourView).animate().rotationXBy(180).start();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            }
        });
```